# MySQL InnoDB Insertion Faster Than MyISAM

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam, bulk-insert

I wrote code that inserts about 15 millions rows into tables in MyISAM and InnoDB for comparsion.

MyISAM and InnoDB are set up with no optimization configuration in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

And tables are created with no indexes.

Insertion are done using statements like

```
INSERT INTO Table (columnA, columnB, columnC) VALUES (?, ?, ?)..." 
(10,000 (?, ?, ?)s) 

db.Exec(stmt, valueArgs...)
```

with `valueArgs` being the actual `VALUES`
 It is widely believed that MyISAM is faster than InnoDB in insertion.

Baron Schwartz, author of the book High Performance MySQL, explained why in this post [Mysql: Insert performance INNODB vs MYISAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16395/mysql-insert-performance-innodb-vs-myisam/16429#16429?newreg=6574f4185f4142ae9a5dd5afe119a6d5).

However, in my experiment, I found out that InnoDB is actually faster than MyISAM. Could anyone give me some insights?

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: InnoDB has undergone many improvements over time, including performance enhancements, and that question you linked is 8 years old. As for MyISAM, while still available its use is deprecated and so doesn't receive nearly as much development attention. Are you looking for something more than that?

Comment: @WillemRenzema Hi, thank you for your valuable insights. I was just doing an experiment and was expecting that MyISAM performs better in bulk insertion than InnoDB. I would like some more deep insights.

Comment: I'd guess (stress guess) that if you went back to version 5.5 of MySQL (or before...), you'd find that MyISAM would perform better than InnoDB - as @WillemRenzema says, InnoDB is still being seriously worked on - whereas MyISAM is being deprecated - so it's hardly surprising that InnoDB is overtaking it in areas where it traditionally performed better - it may well still perform better under some circumstances, but they will become fewer and fewer as time goes on. You might like to look at MariaDB's Aria engine which is a continuation of MyISAM which is under active development?

Comment: or just enjoy fast Innodb with all its other benefits.

Comment: @Vérace Thank you for your insights.

Comment: @danblack Haha. The experiment needs some explanation, you know.

Comment: In fact, InnoDB can't be created without index at all. If no column been used explicitly as PK then InnoDB engine will create a hidden `UNSIGNED BIGINT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT` column and use it as PK for you.

Comment: @Kondybas Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't elaborate well. What I mean is no secondary index.

Comment: @Kondybas - It's actually a 6-byte number, doled out in chunks of 256.  And it does not work quite like auto_inc.

Comment: Upvote -- because you are providing independent proof that the "old wive's tale" is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB has been faster than MyISAM at everything for at least a decade. This shouldn't be a surprise in 2020. There hasn't been a compelling case for using MyISAM in a very long time.

On a workload that involves any concurrency, the difference will be even bigger.

Also, note that Baron's post is from 2012 - and it was probably borderline in terms of accuracy even back then.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you. But could you offer more insights?

Comment: Sure, what additional insight would you like?